# Wordpress database connection error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have just installed a clean version of WordPress on my site and am getting an `Error Establishing Database Connection` message. I have checked the `wp_config` file and, as far as I can see, all seems to be correct.

**This is the precise message:**

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'â€˜markatel_gmateli'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/markatelier/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1489

Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'â€˜markatel_gmateli'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/markatelier/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1515

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/markatelier/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1489) in /home/markatelier/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3592
  Error establishing a database connection'
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your username looks like the first character doesn't belong there. Make sure it doesn't contain any utf8 characters that aren't visible in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

you may check this link..

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/

Hope this helps

Take care and Happy coding

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Fixed now.